# Nslayoutconstraint all button align right

Tags: uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to add two button in the UItableViewCell

But by add the autolayout code, the two button are not align to the right side?

What happen on my code?

```
CGSize winSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
NSDictionary *metrics   = @{ @"width":@(44)};

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"myAddButton":myAddButton,
                                  @"myDeleteButton":myDeleteButton};

NSMutableArray *myConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];

[myConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myDeleteButton(width)]-5-[myAddButton(width)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:myConstraints];

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myAddButton
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myDeleteButton
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];

[self setNeedsLayout];
```

[image]

Comment: how exactly do you want the layout to be?

Comment: something like that

|------------[BTN]-5-[BTN]--|

Comment: two button align to the right side